# Assignment problem using Hungarian method

Tags: linear-programming, operations-research

There are5 jobs to ne assigned one each to five machine and associated cost matrix is as follows
                 Machine
              1.   2.  3.  4.   5
Job. A [11 17  8   16  20]
         B [9.   7. 12.  6    15]
         C [13 16 15  12  16]
         D [21 24 16  28  26]
         E [14.10. 12  11 15]
Find assignment of machines to job that will minimize the total cost?

solved it using Hungarian method but for job A and D I had only one zero that too in same column don't know how to solve further if this happens.

Comment: I would consider moving this to http://or.stackexchange.com

Comment: Use LaTeX please.

Comment: See post on OR.SE https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/574/assignment-problem-using-hungarian-method